# Add prefix to product Url

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need prefix for product url.
Condition is may apply for one particular category not for all.
`http://layway.com/PREFIX/demo.html.`
and both url works simultaneously.
`http://layway.com/PREFIX/demo.html`  and http://layway.com/demo.html.

How i can make this ? 
Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 0):

Hello you will check follow tips

```
Admin -> Manage Categories -> Select your category -> URL Key (right side) -> add your prefix -> check frontend
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not Working.